# How to split string into substrings of identical letters?

Tags: python, string

How do I split a string consisting of lowercase English alphabetical letters into substrings consisting of identical letters - so for an **input**:

```
"aaaabbcccdd"
```

The function should **output** a list:

```
["aaaa", "bb", "ccc", "dd"]
```

Comment: checkout `itertools.groupby`

Comment: Should é and e be classed as identical? What have you tried?

Comment: The string consists of only English alphabetical characters. I'll amend the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following list comprehension using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) will work:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = "aaaabbcccdd"
[''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(s)]
# ["aaaa", "bb", "ccc", "dd"]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with a back reference:

```
import re
from operator import itemgetter
print(list(map(itemgetter(0), re.findall(r'((.)\2*)', "aaaabbcccdd"))))
```

This outputs:

```
['aaaa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'dd']
```

Answer (score 0):

A Counter solution -

```
from collections import Counter

[i*j for i, j in Counter("aaaabbcccdd").iteritems()]
# OP ["aaaa", "bb", "ccc", "dd"]
```

Comment: Did you try this on less orderly input?

Comment: IP `"aaaabbcccddasdffas"` OP `['aaaaaa', 'ccc', 'bb', 'ddd', 'ff', 'ss']` Order should not matter since counter is going to count the alphabets

Comment: You do notice that `'aaaaaa'` is not a substring of the input in that case?

Comment: `lowercase alphabetic letters into substrings consisting of identical letters` substrings consisting of identical letters tell me that all `a`s should be grouped together

Comment: Well, I guess the OP could be clearer or provide a more general example :) Sounds to me like only keeping "substrings" (which your op is not!) together while maintaining order. Just wanted to point out the difference.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I understand your point. I think OP could make the question less ambiguous